# How to set up Postgresql LDAP Auth w/ ldaptls=1 . (postgresql 10)

Tags: postgresql, ldap, postgresql-10

Right now I have the following, which works:

```
host all all all ldap ldapserver=ldap.server.name ldapprefix="DOMAIN\"
```

but to my understanding the connection between the ldap server and pg db isn't encrypted and I need it to be. So i change to:

```
host all all all ldap ldapserver=ldap.server.name ldapprefix="DOMAIN\" ldaptls=1
```

this give me an error saying "could not start ldap tls session connect error".

What are the steps that Im missing in order to get this working? I have a feeling I need to be dropping certs either somewhere on my ldap instance or pg instance (or both) but I don't really have any experience configuring any of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use `ldaptls=1`, then please make sure that you are using the correct certs to connect to the LDAP server.  Also, depending on how LDAP is set up, you may need to add `ldapport=389` to tell Postgres to use the TLS port on the LDAP side.

More information at https://richyen.com/postgres/2018/02/09/making_postgres_talk_to_ldap_with_starttls.html